# Target a specific vendor in Shopify

Tags: html, if-statement, shopify, liquid

I need to target a specific vendor and if the product by this vendor is out of stock disable user ability to add to cart (logic for this part works, just need to focus on the if statement). Here is what I have so far:

```html
{% assign isInStock = true %}
{% if product.vendor == 'PS-Stock' and current_variant.inventory_quantity < 1 %}
    {% assign isInStock = false %}
{% endif %}
```

When I run {{isInStock}} to see what the output is, i get true. Not sure if the product vendor part is wrote correctly as the product i am testing on has 0 inventory quantity so I know the last part of if statement is correct

Answer (score 0):

Try This with Else part

```
    {% assign product_qty = 0 %}
     {% for variant in product.variants %}
     {% if variant.inventory_quantity > 0 %}
     {% assign product_qty = product_qty | plus: variant.inventory_quantity %}
     {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   {% if product.vendor == 'abc' and product_qty > 0 %}
       working
   {%else%}
    not working
   {% endif %}
```